# Gallery view for tablets

Tags: android, android-fragments

I want to implement galary type view for tablets, but it should behave like ViewPager,i.e, when I swipe it left or right, it should move automatically to near end(left or right).

I googled it, but little confused, what is the best way to achive this.

[image]

Comment: As per my way go with `ViewPager` it's very simple and easy to implement.

Comment: Please make your question more clear..if possible then provide some screenshot.

Comment: You can use "Gallery" Object, read about that, if you need one tutorial say me.

Comment: @SimplePlan thanks .... I need to add galary type items in ViewPager and then ViewPager to Fragment ?

Comment: @Aspicas yeah sure please give me !

Comment: I think that is not the best way for that situation, i love ViewPager but... not now, you can use only simple slide XML, gallery item or similar. Look https://github.com/danielme-com/tip-Android--25-Gallery

Comment: If you dont undertand I can open new answer and explain how you can do  one slide for you gallery. @Akhilesh Mani

Comment: @samsad you can think it as galary in tablet...... but galary will move like list and I need it as ViewPager

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54262/discussion-between-akhilesh-mani-and-aspicas).

Comment: okay, go chat then, I explain there

Comment: Are you looking fro this: https://code.google.com/p/android-coverflow/?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Akhilesh Mani Try it:

It's a example using ViewPager:

https://github.com/chiuki/android-swipe-image-viewer

Only put grid inside fragment.